# Should I add more of a trihydrate chemical to a solution if recipe calls for hemihydrate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, water, analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry

I am running phosphate by the ascorbic acid method ([SM 4500-PE](https://www.standardmethods.org/store/ProductView.cfm?ProductID=197), [PDF](http://edgeanalytical.com/wp-content/uploads/Inorganic_SM4500-P.pdf)), and making the antimony potassium tartrate reagent. Standard methods uses $\pu{1.3715 g}$ of $\ce{K(SbO)C4H4O6 * 1/2 H2O}$ per $\pu{500 mL}$, while the chemical I have is $\ce{C8H4K2O12Sb2 * 3 H2O}$.

Should I add proportionately more of the trihydrate chemical to make up for the weight of water? I'm not sure what the exact active ingredient here is, and I realize that there are different chemical formulas besides the water content. But, I am hoping that if I account for the difference in weight of water, then I will get at least closer to the appropriate amount of necessary active reagent.

Comment: I changed the volume from $\pu{500 mL}$ to $\pu{400 mL}$ in your question according to the datasheet info I also provided a link for (I guess you used [this one](http://edgeanalytical.com/wp-content/uploads/Inorganic_SM4500-P.pdf)). $\pu{500 mL}$ is a suggested *flask volume*, not the *volume of antimony potassium tartrate solution*.

Comment: The formatting was a nice change, but the 500mL final volume is correct (they're just suggesting using 400mL as a starting point before diluting to volume). Regardless, still unsure about what proper weight to use. Seems to be working well so far by just using the same 1.3715g as listed in SM, but using the chemical that we bought (trihydrate). I'm not entirely sure what this chemicals purpose is in the color-forming step, but it's not causing any major problems. I'm probably thinking too far into this.

Comment: Your two products are very different, à part from the crystallization water (1/2 or 3). The first product is $\ce{K(SbO)C4H4O6}$⋅1/2 H2O, which can be doubled in $\ce{K2(SbO)2C8H8O12}$⋅H2O. And the second product is $\ce{C8H4K2O12Sb2}$ ⋅3H2O. The number of $\ce{H}$ atoms are not the same in the main tartrate formula : $\ce{C4H4O6}$ in the first formula, and twice, that is $\ce{C8H4O12}$ in the second formula: it is all right, except the number of $\ce{H}$ atoms

Answer (score 0):

The mass percent of Sb in both the hemihydrate and trihydrate is exactly the same. You can verify this by using https://www.webqc.org. Further, upon dissolving in water the chemical species with both these compounds will be identical. Hence, no change in chemistry between these two crystal forms. Hence, weighing the same amount of either hemihydrate or trihydrate will not make any difference in your chemistry. Also, in any analytical analyses, your analyte has to be the limiting reactant (by necessity) and everything else must in excess. In your case you want to determine the concentration of P as o-phosphate. So, P content is the limiting reagent. Acidic molybdenum, ascorbic acid, and antimony potassium tartrate (all under acidic conditions) must be in excess. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: The second formula is factually wrong, as it formally moves structural hydrogen (C-H, C-OH) and oxygen ( SbO+ ) among the crystal water.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdNN4.jpg according to Aldrich. @Poutnik

Comment: @Karsten Yeah, the picture is right, I revoke my prior comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The two are synonyms for the same compound. Potassium antimonyl tartrate sesquihydrate is another synonym.

Tartrate occurs in a fully deprotonated state (ie -4) complexing the antimony(III) with four oxygen atoms each. In other words, tartrate acts as tetradentate tartrato(4-) ligand.

[image]

For a 3D structure, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony_potassium_tartrate

Source: https://www.chemwhat.com/potassium-antimonyl-tartrate-sesquihydrate-cas-28300-74-5/